# Java, ErroMax and Min of Array object data?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, max, min

I need some help with max and min. This code section is from the main method of my Annual Fuel Use class. The program projects my annual fuel usage based on at least three fill ups of my car.

I am calculating the max and min for distance (which is miles traveled), MPG, and price per gallon. From my print statements (not included), I can see it is calculating the max correctly, but it not the min, because it prints the zeros that I initialized the variables to instead of the true minimum values.

*some code*

```
//initialization of array of objects
   AnnualFuelUse[] fillUps = {new AnnualFuelUse (1, 1, 6500, 6800, 9.70, 3.11),
                              new AnnualFuelUse (2, 10, 6800, 7052, 8.10, 3.08),
                              new AnnualFuelUse (3, 20, 7052, 7349, 9.20, 3.15)};
```

*some more code*

```
//calculate Min and Max for distance, MPG, and price per gallon
   double minDist = 0, maxDist = 0;
   double minMPG = 0.0, maxMPG = 0.0, minPrice = 0.0, maxPrice = 0.0;

   Double dMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   Double dMax = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   Double mpgMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   Double mpgMax = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   Double priceMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
   Double priceMax = Double.MIN_VALUE;

   for (int i = 0; i < fillUps.length; i++) {
       if (fillUps[i].getDist() > dMin){
            dMin = fillUps[i].getDist();
            minDist = dMin;
       }     
       if (fillUps[i].getDist() > dMax) {
            dMax = fillUps[i].getDist();
            maxDist = dMax;
       }
       if (fillUps[i].getMilesPerGallon() > mpgMin) {
            mpgMin = fillUps[i].getMilesPerGallon();
            minMPG = mpgMin;
       }    
       if (fillUps[i].getMilesPerGallon() > mpgMax) {
            mpgMax = fillUps[i].getMilesPerGallon();
            maxMPG = mpgMax;
       }             
       if (fillUps[i].getPrice() > priceMin) {
            priceMin = fillUps[i].getPrice();
            minPrice = priceMin;
       }          
       if (fillUps[i].getPrice() > priceMax) {
            priceMax = fillUps[i].getPrice();
            maxPrice = priceMax;
       }
    }
```

It gives me the following data for Distance, MPG, and pricePerGallon

Minimum: 0, 0.0, 0.00
Maximum: 300, 2.3, 3.15

Any help is much appreciated!! :)

Comment: Once you get this problem fixed, I suggest you post your code at [codereview] because there are several things that can be improved in your code. (Just ask for "a general review")

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Is that this website? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, sorry I was supposed to write `[codereview.se]` and not just `[codereview]` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these if-conditions:

```
   if (fillUps[i].getDist() > dMin){
        dMin = fillUps[i].getDist();
        minDist = dMin;
   }     
   if (fillUps[i].getDist() > dMax) {
        dMax = fillUps[i].getDist();
        maxDist = dMax;
   }
```

What you meant to do in the first is `if (fillUps[i].getDist() < dMin)`

There is a big difference between `>` and `<` :)

You are always comparing "is value **more than**" instead of "is value **less than**"

Comment: Oh dear, I *was* comparing the wrong way! Thank you so much, your explanation is very helpful!

Comment: @ReneaS. No problem, actually took me a while to find your error :P I suggest you post your code on [codereview.se] as there are several things that can be improved/simplified in it.